# plotly.blazor await chart.ToImage() hangs if data added to chart

Tags: c#, plotly, blazor-server-side

I have a Blazor server side app and I need to be able to save images of plotly charts to the server to place in dynamically generated reports, so have been trying to use the ToImage() function to achieve this as below:

string i = await chart.ToImage(ImageFormat.Png, 400, 800);

Whilst I have at times been able to make this function work as expected, the trouble comes if the chart data has changed in any way. In these cases chart.ToImage just hangs and nothing is returned.

Below is a simplified version of the source code.  In this case, the ToImage() function only works if no data has been added to the chart.  I based this code off a working example of a scatter chart here: https://delightful-pebble-00ab3ee10.1.azurestaticapps.net/.

I have also tried other methods, such as adding the plot data to the chart IList<ITrace> data source during OnInitializedAsync(), but with the same result that ToImage only works if no data has been added to the chart (that is if I comment out the call to "ExtendData").

I am using visual studio 2022, and version 2.18.2 of Plotly.Blazor.  I have tried earlier versions of Plotly.Blazor in case this is a bug with the latest version, but it did not help.

```
@using Plotly.Blazor
@using Plotly.Blazor.Traces
@using Plotly.Blazor.LayoutLib
@using Plotly.Blazor.Traces.ScatterLib

<h3>Graph</h3>
<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="@SavePlot">Save plot</button>

<PlotlyChart style="height: 60vh; min-height: 350px" @bind-Config="config" @bind-Layout="layout" @bind-Data="data" @ref="chart" />

@code {    
    private PlotlyChart chart;
    private Config config = new()
        {
            Responsive = true
        };

    private IList<ITrace> data = new List<ITrace>
    {
        new Scatter
        {
            Name = "ScatterTrace",
            Mode = ModeFlag.Lines | ModeFlag.Markers,
            X = new List<object>(),
            Y = new List<object>()
        }
    };

    private Layout layout = new()
        {
            Title = new Title { Text = "Scatter" },
            YAxis = new List<YAxis>
        {
            new()
            {
                Title = new Plotly.Blazor.LayoutLib.YAxisLib.Title { Text = "Scatter Unit" }
            }
        }
        };

    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if(firstRender)
        {
            await ExtendData();
        }
    }

    private async Task ExtendData(int count = 100)
    {
        if (!(chart.Data.FirstOrDefault() is Scatter scatter))
        {
            return;
        }

        var max = (int?)scatter.X?.Max();
        List<double> x = new List<double> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5,6 };
        List<double> y = new List<double> { 6, 8, 3, 5, 9, 1 };
        if(!scatter.X.Any() || !scatter.Y.Any())
        {
            scatter.X.AddRange(x.Cast<object>().ToList());
            scatter.Y.AddRange(y.Cast<object>().ToList());
            await chart.React();
        }
        else
        {
            await chart.ExtendTrace(x, y, data.IndexOf(scatter));
        }
    }

    List<string> plotImages = new List<string> { };
    private async Task SavePlot()
    {
        string i = await chart.ToImage(ImageFormat.Png, 400, 800); //This line hangs
        plotImages.Add(i);
    }
}
```